# Converting JPEG in text format from email message source back into JPEG

Tags: email, jpeg, attachment

I received an email a while ago with an image attachment in it. Since then, it seems hotmail has stopped hosting the image for me as when I open the message, the image is no longer available.

However, the message source is still intact, and if I'm not wrong, the message source - in text form - also contains the image.

The problem is of course it is in text form. The part which (I believe) contains the image looks something like this: (Just the first few lines)

> > --Apple-Mail-2--733971985
>
> Content-Disposition: inline;  filename=photo.JPG Content-Id:
>   <3F8BDC26-81F3-4BA2-9071-53E78CB3DB63/photo.JPG>
>
> Content-Type: image/jpeg;     name=photo.JPG Content-Transfer-Encoding:
>   base64
>
> /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4gxYSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAxITGlubwIQAABtbnRyUkdC
>   IFhZWiAHzgACAAkABgAxAABhY3NwTVNGVAAAAABJRUMgc1JHQgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA9tYAAQAA
>   AADTLUhQICAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABFj
>   cHJ0AAABUAAAADNkZXNjAAABhAAAAGx3dHB0AAAB8AAAABRia3B0AAACBAAAABRyWFlaAAACGAAA
>   ABRnWFlaAAACLAAAABRiWFlaAAACQAAAABRkbW5kAAACVAAAAHBkbWRkAAACxAAAAIh2dWVkAAAD
>   TAAAAIZ2aWV3AAAD1AAAACRsdW1pAAAD+AAAABRtZWFzAAAEDAAAACR0ZWNoAAAEMAAAAAxyVFJD

It was sent from my iPhone into Hotmail.

Is this text representing the image that I am missing? I don't believe there is a program out there that can convert this for me, so I am willing to write my own program to do it. Question is, is this even possible?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is entirely possible, by various methods. If you have the entire message source, you could save it into a file (something like `*.eml`) and open it in a mail client (e.g. Mozilla Thunderbird); this should show you the entire message including the attached image.

If not, it's still possible: as you can see from the headers, the image is base64-encoded. You need to revert this transformation - either using your own code (e.g. PHP has [base64_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)), or through various base64-decoders available online (e.g. [this](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp)). The part you want to decode is the block starting with `/9j/4AAQSk` in this case. Rename the resulting file `photo.JPG` (as indicated in the e-mail headers) and you're done.

Note that this requires you to verify that you have put the entire base64-encoded file through the decoder - base64 has no marker to detect the end of file.